# Fractional ideal can be written as a fraction of integral ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, ideals

Let $a$ be arbitrary fractional ideal of fractional field of Dedekind domain $D$. According to Neukirch's book 'Algebraic Number Theory', p. $29$, Corr. $3.9$  reads there exists integral ideal $b$, $c$ such that $a＝b/c$. Here, $b/c$ probably means $bc^{-1}$ where $c^{-1}＝\{x\in\operatorname{Frac} D\,|\,xa\subset D $}, and product is product as a ideal.

My question : How can I get (find) such $b$ and $c$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a$ is finitely generated, so there exists a nonzero $c\in D$ such that $ca\subset D$. So, take $b=ca, c=cD$.